# Mysql group by included the whitespace as same value

Tags: mysql, sql, string, group-by, count

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `ID` VARCHAR(100),
  `Val` VARCHAR(100),
  `Val2` VARCHAR(100)
);
```

and this value

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (`ID`, `Val`, `Val2`)
VALUES
  ('1','1234 ','now'),  // 1 whitespace
  ('2','1234  ','now1'), // 2 whitespace
  ('5','1234  ','now190'), // 2 whitespace
  ('3','1234   ','now2'), // 3 whitespace
  ('4','3123123','now3')
```

I need to group by the data and count how many data that have same value, so i used `group by` and `count`

```
select Val,count(*) from `table1` group by Val
```

the result not what i expect because the data for ID 1,2,5, and 3 is counted as same value like below result

```
Val count(*)
1234    4
3123123 1
```

how could i make the result like expected result below so the value didn't count as same value

```
Val count(*)
1234    1  // 1 whitespace
1234    2  // 2 whitespace
1234    1  // 3 whitespace
3123123 1
```

see this fiddle for [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=87d98017fc329c92d0d7672a4157e74c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just how MySQL does it by default, unless you use some specific collation. A typical workaround is to use `binary`:

```
select binary val, count(*) cnt from table1 group by binary val
```

Or, if you do want a regular string in the resultset rather than a binary string:

```
select max(val) as newval, count(*) cnt from table1 group by binary val
```

Comment: wait let me check that first

Comment: If the VARCHAR column preserves trailing spaces (no db at my fingertips right now), you might try "group by val||'.' " so the trailing blanks survive the implicit trim() or padding in the group by.  You might display the val as '"'||val||'"' so the trailing blanks are identified.  I'm not a big fan of trailing blanks or nulls in any data design!

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett At least trailing blanks are way better than leading :-)

Comment: @Gagantous: here is your [updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e8404c4bb6e75eed6934ad5de76bf535)

Comment: @DavidG.Pickett: it does preserve trailing spaces. Your trick is a good idea, but, since this is an aggregate query, we then need more logic in the `select` clause (since obviously we don't want the trailing dot to appear there): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=37f73f10a17175fece6b114463bac48e

Comment: what do you mean @DavidG.Pickett `group by val||'.'` ? how could i used that ?

Comment: do i have to used `BINARY Val` to call this column for example in `where` clause or in `having` clause or subquery etc ?

Comment: i tried used binary, but it return this value `(BLOB) 16 bytes`

Comment: @Gagantous: ok, this is was not showing in the fiddle. See my edit in the answer for a solution.